# In "inherit", I'm having trouble with the 'return' code

Tags: javascript, class

The following code does not have any problems. It works smoothly.

```js
class Animal{
  constructor(name,age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  getPrint(){
    console.log(`name: ${this.name}\nage:${this.age}`);
  }
};

class Cat extends Animal{
  getPrint(){
    super.getPrint();
  }
}


let animal = new Animal('miyav',9);
let cat = new Cat("mayov",12);
// cat.name = "mayov";
// cat.age = 12;
animal.getPrint()
cat.getPrint()
```

**BUT** When I try to write the above codes with 'return', I get an error.

```js
class Animal{
  constructor(name,age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  getPrint(){
    return `name: ${this.name}\nage:${this.age}`;
  }
};

class Cat extends Animal{
  getPrint(){
    super.getPrint();
  }
}


let animal = new Animal('miyav',9);
let cat = new Cat("mayov",12);
console.log(animal.getPrint());
console.log(cat.getPrint());
```

I think I've fixed the problem, but I still don't understand why.

If we type the following code in the above code, the problem is resolved. **But how?**

```
class Cat extends Animal{}
```

Comment: You're missing the `return` in the subclass `getPrint()`. Your "fix" works because it results in `getPrint()` not being overridden in the subclass.

Comment: @Pointy very pointy sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Pointy mentioned in the comment the second example is missing `return` in the `getPrint()` method of the `Cat` class. `super.getPrint()` returns the value from the super class as expected, but then that value is not returned from the `getValue` method of your subclass. To fix it simply add `return` to the method in your subclass

```js
class Animal{
  constructor(name,age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  getPrint(){
    return `name: ${this.name}\nage:${this.age}`;
  }
};

class Cat extends Animal{
  getPrint(){
    return super.getPrint();
  }
}


let animal = new Animal('miyav',9);
let cat = new Cat("mayov",12);
console.log(animal.getPrint());
console.log(cat.getPrint());
```

The reason `class Cat extends Animal{}` works, is that since you are not redefining the `getPrint` method in the subclass, it automatically inherits it from the superclass (which is probably what you want since your getPrint method is not doing anything extra). So, if you have declare an empty subclass it will get all the methods of the superclass.

```
class Cat extends Animal{}
let cat = new Cat("mayov",12);
console.log(cat.getPrint());
```

this works because the `cat` instance will use the `getPrint` method of the superclass, which is defined correctly, with the `return` keyword.